# Yii role access via accessRules without AuthAssignment table

Tags: php, yii, access-control

Yii framework 1.1.14

I have set the following in my controller:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(

        array(
            'deny', 
            'controllers' => array(
                'site',
                'hotels',
                'channels'
            ),
            'roles' => array('General')
        )

    );
}
```

I have created a custom CDbAuthManager called **CDbAuthManagerExtension**, declared in config/main.php:

```
    'authManager' => array(
        'class' => 'CDbAuthManagerExtension',
        'connectionID' => 'db'
    ),
```

In CDbAuthManagerExtension I have declared my getRoles($user_id) function.

But when I run the code I get the following error:

```
    CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'h2g.AuthAssignment' doesn't exist. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *
FROM `AuthAssignment`
WHERE userid=:userid
```

***I don't want to set up the AuthAssignments table*** and I don't see why it's looking at it when I've specified the roles in the **accessRules** function? Does anyone know how to stop it looking for the AuthAssignments table?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a **`DbAuthManger`** meaning it has to lookup a DB table to get the assignments, it is not looking for the roles as such it is looking for the role assignments to users and determines whether the current user has the authorizations computed *both* based on the roles assigned to him and the roles that are allowed an action.

If you don't want to use the name `AuthAssigment` for the table and use another table you can specify it in your config like this

```
 'authManager' => array(
        'class' => 'CDbAuthManagerExtension',
        'connectionID' => 'db'
        'assignmentTable'=>'MyCustomTable'
    ),
```

There are two other tables you can modify their locations as well read CDbAuthManager doc [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbAuthManager#assignmentTable-detail)

If you however **do not wish to have a table at all** then you should not use the `DbAuthManager` and use the PHPAuthManager, which stores the assignment data in a php file as an array It is configured by CPhpAuthManager see doc [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPhpAuthManager). You can extend this class with your customization and use it in your config instead